# Ruby Array and .max

Tags: arrays, ruby, max

I'm very confused here.

Why does `["4", "5", "29", "54", "4", "0", "-214", "542", "-64", "1", "-3", "6", "-6"].max`

return `6` and not `542`

After deleting 6 from the array, then it returns 542

using `.min` works correctly as well.

/mind-boggled

For reference, I've been using the Ruby IDEs from CodeWars, tutorialspoint.com and labs.codecademy.com/

Comment: It's because you are comparing Strings and not Numbers. "6bd" is lexically greater than "542", and therefore so is "6".

Comment: If you want the largest integer represented by a string in the array `a`, you can write `a.max_by(&:to_i) #=> "542"`.

Answer (score 1):

Because this is a string array, you should convert elements to numbers.

```
["4", "5", "29", "54", "4", "0", "-214", "542", "-64", "1", "-3", "6", "-6"].map(&:to_i).max
=> 542
```

ruby compare words characters by ASCLL value.

```
"6" > "542"
=> true
```

You can get ASCll value of character by `each_byte`:

```
"0123456789".each_byte { |e| puts e }    
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
```

Answer (score 1):

It is an array of strings, so it's treated as if it's alphabetical versus numeric. That means that just like `"za"` would come after `"azzzzzzz"`, `"6"` comes after (is more than) `"5"`. Similarly, `"51"` would come after `"5"` in the same way `"ab"` would come after `"a"` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are compared with [Lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

You can use [`Enumerable#max_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) to specify how to compare them:

```
["4", "5", "29", "54", "4", "0", "-214", "542", "-64", "1", "-3", "6", "-6"].max_by(&:to_i)
#=> "542"
```